# lend argument equivalent for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there an equivalent argument in `ggplot2` for the `lend` argument in base R that lets you make rounded edges for your lines?

I have a plot with a very thick line and I would like to make the edges rounded...

Rounding the edges of lines seems to be default in base R, but I can't figure out how to replicate this with `ggplot`:

```
df = structure(list(x = c(10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8,10.9), y = c(282.083195814139, 281.463374904196, 280.846027959358,280.231142308826, 279.618705353623, 279.008704566105, 278.401127489482, 277.795961737318, 277.193194993064, 276.592815009577)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(lwd = 10)
```

The `lend` argument is no use here.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(lwd = 10, lend=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use geom_path. The argument is lineend.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_path(lwd = 10, lineend = "round")
```